# Customize/modify Rails 3 resources routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm currently writing a rails app that has your regular resource like objects. However I would like to make my resources syncable. My web application uses web offline storage to cache results from the server (user's cannot modify data on server making syncing easier). When I fetch from the server, it returns a hash response like:

```
{
  :new => [...]
  :updated => [...]
  :deleted => [...]
}
```

This is all well and good until I want to have a regular fetch method that doesn't do any sort of syncing and simply return an array of models

Now my question is I want to create a method in my `routes.rb` file that sets up routes so that I have a route to `synced_index` and `index`. Ideally, I'd be able to do something like this:

```
synced_resources :plans
```

And then all of the regular resource routes would be created plus a few extra ones like `synced_index`. Any ideas on how to best do this?

Note: I do know that you can modify resources with `do...end` syntax but I'd like to abstract that out into a function since I'd have to do it to a lot of models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily add more verbs to a restful route:

```
resources :plans do
  get 'synced_index', on: :collection
end
```

Check the [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions) for more information on this.

If you have several routes that are similar to this, then sure, you can add a 'synced_resources' helper:

```
def synced_resources(*res)
  res.each do |r|
    resources(r) do
      get 'synced_index', on: :collection
    end
  end
end
```

Wrap above method in a module to be included in ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper.

Comment: Ended up putting it in an initializer which is necessary since it needs to be executed before routes get drawn. Thanks!